# How can I return data from more than one cell in Google Sheets Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

so I'm currently using Google Sheets for an expense tracker I am making.

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Zbr.png)

At the moment, I am able to display expenses that are more than 100 through this function;

```js
function MORETHANONEHUNDRED(values)
{
  let myArray= [];
  for(let i =0; i<values.length; i++)
  {
    let num = parseInt(values[i]); 
    if(num>100)
    {
      myArray.push(num); 
    }
  }

  return "Here is your array " + myArray; 
}
```

However, this only displays the number, whereas I'd also like the clothing brand to be displayed. How would I make both the expense, as well as the clothing brand corresponding it display to the user if the expense is more than 100?

Thanks!

Comment: In your situation, how do you run your script? For example, I thought that when you run your script as the custom function, for example, the built-in formula like `=FILTER(A2:B,A2:A>100)` might be able to be also used. So I asked about the method for running your script. For example, when you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script, how about `const MORETHANONEHUNDRED = v => v.filter(([a]) => a > 100);`? In this case, `=MORETHANONEHUNDRED(A2:B)` is put to a cell, the result can be obtained. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your response. So currently the way the function is ran is by simply putting `=MORETHANONEHUNDRED(`  in a cell, selecting the values and the clicking enter. In the cell, the user will see "Here is your array" + values>100. I also apologize as I am a beginner and don't know too much about JS. Im building this project through tutorials. I'm still confused as to how exactly I would solve my problem. Where in my function would I put `const MORETHANONEHUNDRED = v => v.filter(([a]) => a > 100);`? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not just use the filter formula provided by tanaike?

Comment: You can also use query native function instead of a script.

Comment: @TheMaster hello, thank you for your reply. i was a bit confused by the comment and I just tried `=FILTER(A2:B,A2:A>100)` and it works perfectly. However this would make my client have to manually enter the range..etc. In my post, the code snippet I included allowed the client to simply put `=MORETHANONEHUNDRED(`, select the values, and then click enter which would give them the return statement. I'd like to make a function where the client can accomplish the same without having the input the range like in `=FILTER(A2:B,A2:A>100)`. Apologies if what I said was confusing and didn't make sense.

Comment: I mean you could input the range similarly. `=FILTER(`, select the range. Or `=QUERY(A2:B," select Col1, Col2 where Col1>100")` as @Mike said. If you must use a script, you'd use Tanaike's script and delete your function entirely. That one line is doing what your 15 lines will be doing.

Comment: @TheMaster and Tanaike thank you very much for your help. I got the result I wanted through your comments. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I'm not sure what you mean. What am I supposed to do? I'd also like to thank you once again for helping me out!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I understood your question was resolved. If my understanding is correct, can you post your solution as an answer? By this, your answer will be useful for other users who have the same issue. If you cannot understand my English, I apologize again.

Comment: @Tanaike Hello and sorry for the late reply. I've tried to post my solution as an answer. Does it appear on this post? If it doesn't, I apologize because I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @aleptian Thank you for your response. I could confirm your post. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, the following line of code will allow me to accomplish what I wanted:

```
const MORETHANONEHUNDRED = v => v.filter(([a]) => a > 100);
```

Thank you to [@Tanaike's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549023/how-can-i-return-data-from-more-than-one-cell-in-google-sheets-apps-script/70571204#comment124710866_70549023) for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in displaying the current selected range of a spreadsheet in a dialog:

```
function dispssdata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  let html = '<style>td{border:1px solid black;text-align:center;padding:1px 2px}</style><table>'
  vs.forEach((r,i) =>{
    html += '<tr>';
    r.forEach((c,j) => {
      html+= `<td>${c}</td>`
    });
    html += '</tr>'
  })
  html += '</table>'
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Display Active Range');
}
```

Active Range:

[image]

Dialog:

[image]